# Can I send 403 to homepage in nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I've placed the following in `.htacess`

```
ErrorDocument 403 /
```

But I'm still getting the default 403 Forbidden message from nginx. Can I send 403 to my homepage in nginx?

Comment: try [server fault](http://serverfault.com/) :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of editing `.htaccess`, I edited `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` with the following:

```
error_page 403 /index.php;
```

And that worked!